# How to filter records with arithmetic operation on columns of different type in Slick 3

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

For example I have this simplified model where timestamp and duration both represent seconds.

`case class Item(id: Int, : Long, duration: Int)`

`val max_timestmap: Long = ???
val stmt = items.filter(x => (x.timestamp + x.duration) <= max_timestamp)
db.run(stmt.result)`

Above will not compile with following error that I have hard time understanding.

`ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Boolean]]]
[error]  and value BooleanCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean]
[error]  match expected type slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
[error]                 filter(x => (x.timestamp + x.duration) <= max_timestamp)`

**Update 1**: 
Seems like the issues stems for the fact that `timestamp` is Long and `duration` is Int. When both are of the same data type it seems to compile.

**Update 2**:
I found this solution to work. Cast duration to Long using `x.duration.asInstanceOf[Rep[Long]]` or probably more appropriate `x.duration.asColumnOf[Long]`

Comment: Does `(p => p.age <= 23)` work? Aren't you missing an import?

Comment: duration is an int? what does that mean, is it the number of minutes, seconds, hours? just convert everything to the same type

Comment: Yes, duration is in seconds and it is represented such way in the table. Is it possible to do conversion without changing current data type in the table?

Comment: duration.toLong

Comment: Tried that before but duration is not `Int` but `Rep[Int]`, `duration.asInstanceOf[Rep[Long]]` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

According to Slick documentation [COMING FROM SQL TO SLICK](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html#main-obstacle-semantic-api-differences):

> Arithmetic operation in different types require explicit casts using `.asColumnOf[T]`.

As you have already discovered, you have to explicitly cast `duration` to `Long`: `x.duration.asColumnOf[Long]`.

Answer (score 1):

Though not very helpful in telling the exact problem, the error message makes sense if one looks at method `filter` and trait/object `CanBeQueryCondition` in [Query.scala](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala):

```
sealed abstract class Query[+E, U, C[_]] extends QueryBase[C[U]] { self =>
  ...
  def filter[T <: Rep[_]](f: E => T)(implicit wt: CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, U, C] =
    withFilter(f)
  ...
}

...

trait CanBeQueryCondition[-T] extends (T => Rep[_])

object CanBeQueryCondition {
  implicit val BooleanColumnCanBeQueryCondition : CanBeQueryCondition[Rep[Boolean]] =
    new CanBeQueryCondition[Rep[Boolean]] {
      def apply(value: Rep[Boolean]) = value
    }
  implicit val BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition : CanBeQueryCondition[Rep[Option[Boolean]]] =
    new CanBeQueryCondition[Rep[Option[Boolean]]] {
      def apply(value: Rep[Option[Boolean]]) = value
    }
  implicit val BooleanCanBeQueryCondition : CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean] =
    new CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean] {
      def apply(value: Boolean) = new LiteralColumn(value)
    }
}
```

As pointed out by @Federico Pellegatta, the explicit cast requirement leads to `T` = `Nothing` (`T <: Rep[_]`) for the implicit parameter `CanBeQueryCondition[T]`, thus the reported error.